# How to review Apple Podcasts app?

Tags: iphone, podcasts, ios

Recent iPhone update also updated Podcasts app. Which is now missing lots of features and it is broken.
I found Apple Podcasts app in itunes but there is no Review tab or button. I like to write a review for apple but don't know how. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podcasts is part of iOS, not on the App Store, therefore you can't review it on the App Store.

You can send feedback to Apple through Apple Feedback:

- http://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html

Comment: IOS-9 is not in that page yet. So i can't use it yet.